# How do I make a perfect colored circle inside an HTML table cell that stays round and scales with the table?

Tags: html, css

All the circle-inside-table-cells solutions I see require me to specify the widths and heights of the table, or elements of it, with pixels. I tend to specify table/table-element sizes with percentages. That way I can expect a user to be able to shrink their browser window and everything adjusts responsively.

I need perfect colored circles inside some of my table elements. It would be nice if there was centered text in it, but that is unimportant compared to just having a circle. That said, if there was text it would only be a couple characters max. I really just need the circles now and I'm guessing the text is a lot more complex so we can ignore that for now, unless it's easy enough to include.

How can I create circles that stay round and shrink/expand according to whatever available height there is in the table cell? If a table cell is wide and short, the circle would have more space to either side of it, as an example, but stay round.

I am not at all against using svg or something similar... or even a graphic... if that makes this work. However, my table dynamically renders with React and I'll be dynamically applying a class or id to cause the circles to appear and disappear. So that has to be possible, and I'm not sure how that would work with svg or an equivalent or a graphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a radial-gradient background image using closest-side for a circle.

```
background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red 0%, red 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%)
```

Here's a simple example:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
table {
  width: 30%;
  height: 40%;
}
td {
 background-color: pink;
}
td.circle {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red 0%, red 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>cell 1</td>
<td class="circle">cell 2</td>
<td>cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red 50%, cyan 50%);`: This would be enough (without the need of the oher properties) ;) or `background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red 50%, transparent 50%) cyan;`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I always tend to spell things out but it's nicer cutting out the unnecessary bits as you have.

Comment: You nailed it!  I am so relieved! I can resize the window, and the circle(s) stay centered and round. The table cells also stay the same size; sometimes in trying things a cell with a circle would become a different size. Wow.

Comment: Just sitting here, resizing the window. Staring at the perfect circles. Resizing it again. Staring at the perfect circles.

Comment: Glad it worked! It's always feels good/correct when styling and content can be separated out like this.

Answer (score 0):

The Following will create a perfect circle 100% of the width.

CSS Style

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
.circle{
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
}

.circle:after{
    content: "";
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

For 100% height try this

CSS

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="circle">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" height="100%">
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6hwdso4e/

Then just make sure your table cell is position relative.

Comment: It's strange... when I apply this class to a table cell I get a gigantic circle. It's as though the size is 50% of the overall window, as opposed to the table cell.

Comment: Because your container need to have a relative position set

Comment: I'm still having trouble with it. I should take a break and come back to it with fresh eyes.

Comment: Just make sure your container div is set within the table cell inspect it is it fitting or expanding outside the cell? You will be ok as long as its position is set to absolute or relative. I love JS but, No JS is needed here did you check the fiddle above?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setCircles() {
  var bounding = document.getElementById("table").querySelector("td").getBoundingClientRect();
  
  var circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
  if (bounding.width >= bounding.height) {
     for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].style.width = bounding.height+"px";
      circles[i].style.height = bounding.height+"px";
     }
  } else if (bounding.width < bounding.height) {
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].style.width = bounding.width+"px";
      circles[i].style.height = bounding.width+"px";
     }
  }
}
setCircles();
document.addEventListener("load", setCircles);
window.addEventListener("resize", setCircles);
```

```css
#table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 5000px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle">text</div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hadn't gone the JavaScript route yet... I try to set this up.

Comment: Thank you for this! The #table specifies a height and width by pixels which won't work. when I commented those lines out, the circle appears, but it is no longer round as the table cell is wider than taller. This is the issue I am used to. I need for it to stay round even in a non-square table cell.